# Procedural Rougness texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm looking to create a procedural basic rough texture in blender with some texture nodes. Can someone either share a node tree or a link to a video on it? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, please a picture of the kind of texture you would like to reproduce

Comment: I don't have a picture of the texture. I just want to rough the surface up a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you mean roughness as a 2D effect or 3D effect.

For 2D roughness you can use a *Noise* (or this kind of texture) as a factor in a mix between a glossy and a non glossy material:

[image]

For 3D roughness you need to plug a *Noise* (or this kind of texture) into a *Bump* node that you plug into the Normal sockets of your nodes. Here I've mixed 2 *Noise Texture* nodes into a *MixRGB* (try *Overlay* or *Darken* or *Lighten* mode) in order to have some smoother areas.

[image]

If you're not fully procedural and use an *Image Texture*:

In the case of a 2D effect, if you use an *Image Texture* you can create something without any unwrap, I guess it's the quickest way:

- Prepare your dirt texture (a simple black and white jpg is ok).
- Create this nodes setup: *Texture Coordinate* (*Object* output) > *Mapping* > *Image Texture* > *ColorRamp* > *Factor* socket of a *Mix Shader*.
- In the Image Texture, load your dirt image, choose *Box* instead of *Flat* so that the texture will be projected all around the object. You may need to play with the *Blend* factor to avoid any seam effect.
- In the *Mix Shader*, plug the 2 materials, the one that is supposed to be the glossy and the rough one.
- You can play with the *Location* and Scale of the *Mapping* node, but don't play with the *Rotation* if you want to avoid stretching.

[image]
[image]

In the case of a 3D effect, same setup on the left, then:

- Plug your *Image Texture* node into the *Height* socket of a *Bump* node.
- Plug the *Bump* into the *Normal* sockets of your *Diffuse* and *Glossy* nodes.
- Here I've used a (*Math*) *Multiply* node instead of a *ColorRamp*. - Play with the *Strength* of the *Bump* to increase the 3D effect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The recent versions of Blender have Map Range node but you could have had it before as a node group. I find it a good way to control some important values when you need to have some variations but on a certain scale.

Comment: oh ok I don't know anything about it

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put a noise (procedural) texture instead of image texure as this node tree shows,and you get a basic rough shader.[how-to-make-a-bump-map-from-a-texture-paint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98587/how-to-make-a-bump-map-from-a-texture-paint)